# css3 drop shadow property left right bottom

Tags: html, css

I need to make this using only css and css3 drop shadows
Please help to make like this using css...

Image : http://technocodes.us/Lab/Html/vidbees/img/frame.png

Comment: Please show us your attempt. Also, I don't think this can be done with just drop-shadows. It would need additional pseudo-elements to be added.

Comment: Btw, by explicitly mentioning the "url" you are exposing yourself(server) to exploits. I'd suggest you to use an image hosting site like [postimage](http://postimage.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADDED MORE TO THE ANSWER:

I looked into this. I believe this is the solution. **Not using images at all, only CSS.**

This is not the full solution, but I believe this is the solution. You should get the idea and solution to run from from here I think:

This is the result:
(Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwfL5azw/3/ )
Here is the place that inspired me, and I lend code from: http://www.themeshock.com/css-drop-shadow/

[image: This is the result]

The HTML:

```
<div class="main-box">
     <div class="box_shadow">Here is my content
         <div class="sh_bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.main-box {
padding: 0 0 0 30px; /*just for the box's content*/
}
.sh_bottom:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
z-index: -1;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: -20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: -20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: -20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-transform: skew(-10deg,-10deg) translate(40px,-15px);
transform: skew(-10deg,-10deg) translate(40px,-15px);
-moz-transform: skew(-10deg,-10deg) translate(40px,-15px);
}
.sh_bottom:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
z-index: -1;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 20px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-transform: skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-40px,-15px);
-webkit-transform: skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-40px,-15px);
transform: skew(10deg,10deg) translate(-40px,-15px);
}

.box_shadow {
padding:20px;
width: 374px;
min-height: 200px;
margin: auto;
background: #ccc;
border: 5px solid white;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 0px 1px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

MORE:

[image: With shadow on the side]

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uwfL5azw/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is only a little example of drop shadows.

For an example more helpful, I need of you code, or a web page with a result similar at your.

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Thank you and bye,
*Giacomo*

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/udq412fe/1/) it is made of two `divs`

```css
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:grey;
    margin:20px;
    border:2px solid white;
    box-shadow:0px 16px 20px black;
}
#b {
    
    position:absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 250px solid transparent;
    border-right: 250px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid white;
    margin-left:-130px;
    margin-top:-17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Without using two divs [Fiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/udq412fe/3/)

```css
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:grey;
    margin:20px;
    border:2px solid white;
    box-shadow:0px 16px 20px black;
}
#b {
    
    position:absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-left: 250px solid transparent;
    border-right: 250px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid white;
    margin-left:-130px;
    margin-top:-17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```